# Debugging method called from BeginInvoke(...) - Locks debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am using BeginInvoke to start a delegate, but the issue is I cannot debug in the
method invoked through BeginInvoke. When a breakpoint is set inside
the method, the IDE pauses (usually), then once the breakpoint is hit
and a continue is attempted (F10 or F11), the debugger hangs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause for the hang is an implicit property or `.ToString` evaluation which causes a deadlock in the CLR and hence debugger.  Try disabling this and repeating the scenario

- Tools -> Options -> Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable implicit property evaluation"

When the debugger implicitly or explicitly evaluates functions it does so on a hijacked thread in the CLR.  This thread is not the thread on which you are currently debugging and all other threads are suspended during this operation.  Hence if any of the `ToString` or property methods do a thread sensitive operation it can very easily cause a deadlock.

The debugger effectively executes methods in the debugger window synchronously from the UI thread and consequently it locks Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Great!! I have unchecked "Call TOString() on objects in variables windows(C# only)" and it solves my problem. Thx! Would you please provide more detailed info on the reason?

Comment: @Carlos_Liu added a bit more detail on why this happens

Answer (score 0):

I found JaredPar's solution useful, but have a different scenario where it is useful.  We found in VS2005 with .Net 3.5 that the debugger did not hang, it simply would not stop inside the delegate method.  In fact, evidence showed that the delegate method was never called.  Once we un-cheked the *Enable implicit property evaluation*, debugging the method was possible, and the method completed successfully.